# Avoiding race conditions in a toy example

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a hypothetical scenario as follows:

```
class Foo {
   int parentId;
   String data;
}
```

I have a multithreaded application which is processing a stream/`List<Foo>` objects and the purpose of the app is to check if each Foo's parentId exists in a DB and, if it doesnt, create a Parent object and store it in a DB table with the parentId set.

The problem is that when two `Foo` objects (A and B) with the same parentId (`A.parentId` = `B.parentId`) come along. During the processing, A checks if `A.parentId` exists -> it doesnt -> create a new Parent object with `parentId` = `A.parentID`. But, B has already checked if `B.parentId` exists (before A can finish creating the new Parent object) and B also comes to the same conclusion and created a new Parent object with parentId = `B.parentId`.

Now, I have two Parent objects in the end with the exact same parentId in the database. I know I can have constraints set up to avoid the duplication but I am trying to understand if there is standard solution to problems such as these (race conditions?). Assume also that I cannot grab an exclusive lock on the db table.

Comment: I would use a ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Lock> where the key into the map is your parentId

Comment: How is this a multithreading problem? Wouldn't you have the same issue with a single stream containing duplicate IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You should need to add a synchronized method or synchronized code block to wrap your code logical of checking parentId exists and create parent object.

If the parent object is unique, another way to avoid creating two duplicated parent object is creating a unique index of the table on the parentId column

Answer (score 0):

If only one multithreaded application instance,I would prefer `ConcurrentHashMap <Integer,CountDownLatch>` to let only one thread to insert parentId.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, CountDownLatch> tmp = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();// global variable in the process class

public void process(Foo f) {
            //db op: test if parent id exists
            if (f.parentId not exists) {
                CountDownLatch a = tmp.get(f.parentId);
                //no one update parent id
                if (a == null) {
                    a = new CountDownLatch(1);
                    CountDownLatch old = tmp.putIfAbsent(f.parentId, a);
                    //no one update exactly
                    if (old == null) {
                        insert parent id
                        a.countDown();
                        //tmp.remove(f.parentId);//line 1
                        process f
                    } else {
                        old.await();//here may throw interrupted exception;you may retry or just ignore according to your application.
                        process f
                    }

                }
            }
    }
```

In the code above,tmp grows(memory leak) if we do not remove CountDownLatch instances which will never be used after parent id was inserted into db.The code in line 1 is what I say.But if I just remove it like line 1,there is possibility that one check parent id not exists and get CountDownLatch return null,but in fact parent id was inserted into db due to we remove the CountDownLatch in other thread.I have no idea about how to handle this situation.

If there are many instances, I would install a dispatcher before all these instances to dispatch same parentId to same instance.For example,three instances denote by 1,2,3; When a Foo comes in,I will check its parentId and decide which instance will process this Foo,like a load balancer.

Comment: I give you an upvote if you write actual code rather than pseudo code.

Comment: @bhspencer  I will try it,I can only give some pseudo code when dealing with db.

Answer (score -2):

Other than 2 solutions you posted in your question, you can look at Sync/Co-ordination frameworks like `AKKA` or `ZOOKEEPER` to implement co-ordination and synchronization among the processes as well.

Out of curiosity, why is that child comes into existence before a Parent in your Case?

Comment: This is really a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @DownVoters, i guess that you overlooked the answer. I had mentioned that the use of `AKKA` and `ZOOKEEPER` to solve the problem.

Comment: Suggesting some external product is not an answer.

Comment: Also using Zookeeper or Akka is only necessary if you have a set of distributed processes, They are not appropriate for a single process multithreaded problem.

Comment: @bhspencer what made you think so that suggesting an external product\framework is not an answer?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend a [sic] tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow ", That is a quote from the reasons to close a question section. If that is a reason to close a question it is certainly a reason to downvote your answer.